# wkhtmltopdf Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, wkhtmltopdf, engineyard

I'm getting the following error:

```
wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I install the missing library on engineyard server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engineyard servers use gentoo, to install the library run the following command on the server:

```
sudo emerge libpng:1.2
```